# Native iOS web app + jquery mobile. Saving current state of application

Tags: jquery, ios, html, jquery-mobile

I'm using the jquery mobile single page template. Navigation is as follows:

```
index.html -> page1.html?param1=x -> page2.html?param1=x&param2=y
```

On page2.html there is a link to a PDF file that opens in Mobile Safari.  After I return to the running web app, it reloads and starts at `index.html.`  This is only a problem when running the web application from the home screen.

I'd like it so that when I return to the web application I remain at

`page2.html?param1=x&param2=y`.

I'd also like it so that when I hit the back button on that page to return me to

`page1.html?param1=x.`

I believe I have to use `localStorage` to save the state of the application but I'm not sure what information needs to be saved to maintain my page history.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `localStorage` to save the state but I don't think that will stop the autoreload behavior you're describing. There is an example with a Tic-Tac-Toe game on Apple's website:

https://developer.apple.com/library/safari/documentation/iPhone/Conceptual/SafariJSDatabaseGuide/Introduction/Introduction.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40007256-CH1-SW1

I'm not completely familiar with the jQuery Mobile and how the single-page templates work, but if you can save the current URL (e.g. page2.html?param1=x&param2=y) via `localStorage` then you'll need to add some code to your page(s) that looks for this stored value and redirects if present.

**Rough example:** You could probably put something like this in your code, after jQuery has loaded:

```
$('a').on('click', function(){          
    localStorage.currentURL = this.href
});
```

Now every time you click on a link that value is getting saved to `localStorage`.

Then at the top of the relevant page(s) you can put something like this:

```
if (localStorage.currentURL && location.currentURL != location.href) {
    location.href = localStorage.currentURL;
}
```

This part looks for a value saved to `localStorage` and, if it finds one, redirects the page to the correct URL. It also makes sure the saved value isn't the page you're already on, otherwise we'd end up in an infinite loop.

Technically the reloading behavior remains but your app can redirect itself based on where you last were. This is why you'd probably want to put this directly after the opening `<body>` tag and before any other scripts have loaded — so that it loads and redirects quickly.

If you want a solution that truly subverts the reloading behavior I think you'll have to explore using the HTML5 Offline Application Cache which Apple has documentation for here:

https://developer.apple.com/library/safari/documentation/iphone/conceptual/safarijsdatabaseguide/OfflineApplicationCache/OfflineApplicationCache.html

Actually, I think that technically the reload behavior here still persists, but because all of the assets are cached locally it's quick enough that you probably wouldn't notice.

Hope that helps!